# Make images stack for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

I am trying to create a page with two images side by side on desktop, then have those images stack for mobile.  I am making my browser window smaller to simulate a smaller screen.  The images are not stacking on mobile.  Here's my html:

```
<div class="container-lp">
    <div class="col-2-lp">
      <h4><a href="#">Interior Decorating</a></h4>
      <div class="overlay">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://pjstagingdecorating.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Interior-Decorating-Level-1B.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2-lp last-lp">
      <h4 class="landing-page"><a href="#">Home Staging</a></h4>
      <div class="overlay">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://pjstagingdecorating.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Home-Staging-Level-1B.jpg" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my CSS for desktop:

```
.container-lp {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
}

.col-2-lp {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.last-lp {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.col-2-lp img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

And my media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 600px) {
  .col-2-lp {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .last-lp {
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot test min-device-width media query on pc browser just change it to min-width and everything will work

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in your code. You cannot test device media queries on pc browser try this instead

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 600px) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I added that code plus a min width of 320px on each image.  Now I am having a strange issue: Between widths of 601px and 999px, the image is taking up 50% of the browser width in the column.  I don't have any media query in place for these widths; shouldn't the browser just use my general code?

Comment: Just got this working, here is my fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/p3xazy58/  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if this functionality is all you need, I would suggest looking up bootstrap. You can achieve the same thing without touching the CSS like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><img src="#"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><img src="#"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

Set everything to be 100%, then above a certain width set it 50%, then it should go side by side.

```
.image {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
  .image {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qpkrpk4/4/) that shows a simple example